# Шипы в профайлере

Tags: unity3d

Есть игра в ней довольно таки много объектов, они появляется и исчезают (делал пул но становилось только хуже).

Также все эти объекты движутся с помощью:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.position -= new Vector3(20 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}
```

Tris ~7.5k а Verts ~15k:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки графики:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также есть данные с профайлера в формате .data
которые можно загрузить в unity и посмотреть (только нужно сначала распаковать из 7z а то без сжатия они много весят)

данные: http://www.mediafire.com/file/pq3ocr5r1c1ix1w/Profiler_lags.7z/file

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это уже 3й вопрос? Хватит удалять старые и постить новые, что сложного все одном месте редактировать?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker тут я постарался как можно больше дать информации

Comment: Если в дип профайле выделить шипы, там должно быть показано что их вызывает, и время затраченное на выполнение всех функций. Так можно узнать причину тормозов.

Comment: @trollingchar там player loop scene culing и итд

Comment: Ну я не устану повторять - этот вопрос не несет никакого смысла, "скачайте", "посмотрите сами". Добавляйте в вопрос всю информацию, иначе никто за него не возьмется, как и в прошлые 2 раза.

Comment: @AimonZ. что из перечисленного тратит больше времени? Можете в режим иерархии переключить, по мне, так удобнее.

Comment: Написал новый пул стало намного лучше но, фризы есть ещё